# Help identifying a distribution

Tags: curve-fitting, log-linear

I'm seeing data whose rank-frequency curve is nearly log linear (*b* e^(*a* *x*)) but where the top few frequencies are higher than expected. The top fits a Bradford distribution well, and the middle is nearly perfectly log linear.

[image: Fitted curve]

f = *b* e^(*a* *x*) (*x*+*c*)/(*x*+*d*) is variant of the equation above that fits the data well:

[image: Hybrid curve]

where c and d are about 20 and 4, respectively, and a is about -0.007. Obviously this is just some *ad hoc* curve fitting, but I wondered if there are any standard probability/frequency distributions which looks similar or has a comparable equation?

Comment: Could it be something related to Zipf distribution?

Comment: They have a similar Zipf pattern but in double logarithmic https://www.nngroup.com/articles/zipf-curves-and-website-popularity/